# How to execute shell script in cygwin?

Tags: windows, shell, cygwin

the name.sh already save in C:\Documents and Settings\user, i type sh name.sh

sh: testing.sh: No such file or directory

any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://superuser.com/questions/258587/how-to-execute-shell-script-in-cygwin).

Answer (score 11):

You can just type `./name.sh` and your script should run.

If your current directory is not in your `$PATH`, adding the `./` tells the shell to look there.

The other possibility is that you're not currently in the right directory. If the result of `pwd` shows you are not in `C:\Documents and Settings\user`, then you will need to `cd` to that directory, or move the script to whatever directory you are in.

Answer (score 2):

Add ./ in front of the name. ./name.sh